# Why does virtual terminal throw error on eval while Gnome Terminal works?

Tags: bash, eval, ubuntu-18.04

I sometimes use the virtual terminal on my Ubuntu (18.04.5) laptop and commands return error.
For example I do:

1. ctrl+alt+F3
2. login on my account

```
bob@mylaptop:$ ls
file1 file2 file3
-bash: eval: line 2: premature end of file (EOF) when looking for matching "'"
-bash: eval: line 3: syntax error: premature end of file
```

(*sorry, errors are in French so it's a personal translation*)

I understand that there is a missing quote in the `eval` code, but I don't know how to fix it.

Commands still return expected results, and I don't find any missing quote in `~/.bashrc`. My normal terminal (Gnome Terminal) is working just fine.

### Edit :

Question moved to [Ask_Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/1332475/1033725)

The error begin with `-bash:` and not `bash:`

Comment: That might have nothing to do with it, but do you have a ` ~/.bash_login` or `~/.profile` file? The obvious difference between the terminal emulator and the virtual console is that the latter opens a login shell.

Comment: I have the second one, but there is no missing quote here.

Comment: You got this messages with ls or with another command ?

Comment: SO is for programming questions only, so OS configuration is [off-topic](/help/on-topic). Please ask on [ubuntu.se] instead.

Comment: check you `PS1`

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano Running `echo $PS1` return  `\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]bob@mylaptop\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$`

@ctac_ yes it do the same thing with every command, including enter.

Comment: Is asked on Ask_Ubuntu, waiting other vote to close it. @wjandrea

Comment: try `PS1='% '` in your virtual console and see if the error goes away

Comment: Nothing change @DiegoTorresMilano